# open from from newly entered record before save

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access 2007. We enter a new record on a form. Then we click a button which has a macro action to open another form. What can I do to make the form open but linked to the new record? I understand that I need the primary key on the new form etc. If the record was saved I can make the second form open with that data. But My Question is when it's still a new record/form we need to navigate directly onto the linked form...

Please share some direction on this..

Comment: See my answer to a very similar question on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/313383/link-new-record-to-existing-form/313952#313952  As per that post, I would suggest that it might make more sense to use a main form/subform than a popup form, particularly if there's a parent/child relationship between the records being edited in the two forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question you need to do the following:

1. Add a new record on Form1
2. Click a button on Form1 to open Form2
3. When Form2 opens, it contains the info from Form1

I have a process that does something similar in my database and we do things this way.

1. The users have a form to enter new records
2. They use a button click to post the new data to the table.  During this process, I return the primary key to the new record. Then the final process of the button click, I tell it to open the new form, and populate it with the primary key I just grabbed.
3. New form opens using the PK for the record.

My code for the button click is in VBA:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
  Dim sqlStr As String
  Dim RptID As Variant

  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tble_Investigations", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  ' here you need to add each of your fields from the form
  rst.AddNew
      rst![Table.Column1] = Me![FormField1]
      rst![Table.Column2] = Me![FormField2]
      rst![Table.Column3] = Me![FormField3]
  rst.Update

  ' my sql string to return the new ID of the record I just added
  sqlStr = "Select Max([ID]) as [MaxOfID] from tble_Investigations;"
  Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlStr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  rst1.MoveFirst

  RptID = rst1![MaxOfID]

  'here we open the Form2 with the new id.
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_Details", acNormal, , "[ID]= " & RptID, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Frm_New", acSaveYes

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Based on what you are telling it sounds like you are doing the following:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
  Dim sqlStr As String
  Dim RptID As Variant

  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("t_Evaluation", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  ' here you need to add each of your fields from the form
  rst.AddNew
      rst![ExecutionLeadOrg] = Me![ExecutionLeadOrg] 'the field from your form that matches the table column
      rst![TitleID] = Me![TitleID]
      rst![t_Evaluation.EvalTypeID] = Me![t_Evaluation.EvalTypeID]
      rst![SectionID] = Me![SectionID]
      rst![LOBEvaluation] = Me![LOBEvaluation]
      'you need to continue doing this for each field on your form
  rst.Update

  ' my sql string to return the new ID of the record I just added
  sqlStr = "Select Max([EvaluationID]) as [MaxOfID] from t_Evaluation;"
  Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlStr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  rst1.MoveFirst

  RptID = rst1![MaxOfID]

  'here we open the Form2 with the new id.
  DoCmd.OpenForm "f_LOBevalPopUpEntry", acNormal, , "[EvaluationID]= " & RptID, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "F_EvalNew", acSaveYes

End Sub
```

Comment: I added your suggestion to my buttons code - It bombs and when I debug it's at rst!Status = "OPEN"  I am not sure what to replace "OPEN" with??????

Comment: As I said that is my code.  What you need to do is add your fields from your table. if you edit your OP with your table structure, I will show you what I mean.

Comment: Yes I understand and I have put in my code to reflect my tables and ID fields etc. But I don't understand this rst!Status = "OPEN"???

Comment: That was is one of my fields that I am adding to the table. Let me edit my code

Comment: This is what I have. The copy to table=t_Evaluation the key=EvaluationID.  New table=f_LOBevalPopUpEntry. I think I have everything right except the rst!Status...  ("t_Evaluation", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
  rst!Status = "EvaluationID"
  rst.Update
  sqlStr = "Select Max([Eval_ID]) as [MaxOfID] from t_Evaluation;"
     RptID = rst1![MaxOfID]
  DoCmd.OpenForm "f_LOBevalPopUpEntry", acNormal, , "[Eval_ID]= " & 
  DoCmd.close acForm, "F_EvalNew", acSaveYes

Comment: Are you adding data into your t_Evaluation table? I added some code based on your comment

Comment: I am trying your code now.  The first data entered your code would write to t_Evaluation.  Then when the second form (linked) opens, that data will be written to a seperate table.  So to answer your question - Yes.

Comment: You are very helpful,thank you.  Your additional comments in the code have me confused as to where to put my field.  Could you please add 1-2 generic fields and show me how/where to add my fields. I have to add 20 fields to your code to post back to the table.

Comment: If you would edit your original post, and place your table structure that you are inserting into and the fields from the form.  I can help.

Comment: I do not have edit privileges.                                 Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("t_Evaluation", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) ExecutionLeadOrg, TitleID, t_Evaluation.EvalTypeID, SectionID, LOBEvaluation, LOBlegalApprover, LOBcomplianceApprover,LOBAdditionalApprovers,
  LOBcompImpact , LOBcompImpactDESC, LOBLegalMemoLink, HiLevelLOBTimingSumm, HiLevelLOBCostSumm, LOBStrategicImpactSumm, RuleHiTimingSumm, RuleHiCostSumm
  PlannedFunding , LOBInternationalImpact, LOBIntnalImpactDESC, LOBcustomerImpact, LOBCusAudienceImpact, LOBassociateImpact, EarlyArchLeansLink
    ' here you

Comment: This is all the char it allowed me to add.  As you can see, From Set rst = I've added my 20 fields, but I don't think I am doing it right?

Comment: I updated my code above to include a few of your fields so you can see how you should do it

Comment: Wow, so close: Added the fields, ran it, bombed towards the end on this line: Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlStr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Should I be changing something in it?

Comment: if you run this query does it work, Select Max([EvaluationID]) as [MaxOfID] from t_Evaluation;

Comment: VERY Close now.... Because you asked to run that select, I realized the Key is Eval_ID for that table and the one being opened is EvaluationID.  Now, the second form opens but not linked, it's in add mode..?  Trying to find this problem - suggestions?

Comment: On your second form, go to design view and properties then Data tab, what do you have the Record Source?  In this place you need the name of the table you will be pulling the data from.

Comment: The Data Source was to a Query that created the 2nd form.  I modified the form so the data source could be the table only.  but still, the second form comes up in add mode. I don't see anything including your code to make it come up in add, so is there something missing to populate the 2nd form???

Comment: My second form does not use the same table as the first form. So the Key is no longer available on the 2nd form.  I am going to recreate the 2nd form with a query again making sure the key from the 1st table i spart of the form....  You are a fantastic help.  This application is due in the morning and it is Very important.  Can't thank you enough for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to save the current record, and then launch the next form to the SAME record. As long as the form launched is model then you be fine. And to advoid any confusing here, a model form is HUGE difference then launching that of a dialog form.

However, you can also consider launching a dialog form.

When you return to that previous form, Access as a general rule will show any updates.

The code you need is this:

```
If me.Dirty = True then Me.Dirty = false
Docmd.OpenForm "name of next form",,,"id = " & me!id
```

Furthermore, when launching another form in a series of operations, it is a good idea to force a record save as per above anyway.

So, only the above two lines of code is required.

Comment: I've tried to get this to work, this is what I have, including the final command to open and close the forms.  Could you please help me with the syntex?                                           Private Sub Label143_Click()
If me.Dirty = True then Me.Dirty = false Docmd.OpenForm "f_LOBevalPopUpEntry",,,"Eval_ID = " & me!Eval_ID;
DoCmd.OpenForm "f_LOBevalPopUpEntry", acNormal, , "[Eval_ID]= " & RptID, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
DoCmd.close acForm, "F_EvalNew", acSaveYes
End Sub